# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. Error

Tags: .net, post, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, google-cloud-print

Im trying with the google cloud print. The /search api of the cloud printing is used for getting the printerid and xsrf token..so im posting the data and trying to get response but everytime i post im getting  The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden..is it cross domain problem or what problem?

```
     string str= TextBox1.Text;
     var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search?output=json&clientid=" + str);
     request.Method = "POST";
      SetupWebRequest (request);
      string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
      byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
      request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
     Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
     // Write the data to the request stream.
     dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
     // Close the Stream object.
     dataStream.Close();
     WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
```

Comment: Did your code managed to print on specific printer using c# and google cloud print???

Answer (score 1):

You must pass an `Authorization: Bearer <access token here>` header in order for Google to authenticate your request. Merely passing a clientid parameter in the URL is not enough.

See the developers guide for more information on how to obtain an access token:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appDevGuide